In webpack-dev-server, how to custom dev server router to control webpack compiler instance
I meet this err
above err, in sometimes, dev-server cannot auto update node_modules/pkg change, so I hope a way to manaully update new code with webpack compiler.inputFileSystem.writeFile to update code
so I hope a way to custom webpack-dev-server router and access webpack compiler
